# ClipDrawable not working when used as layout background for widget

Tags: java, android, android-widget, android-linearlayout

I'm attempting to make a simple widget that displays the battery percentage both textually and graphically in a widget. The textual part works without problem, but I'm having great difficulty getting the widget to graphically update.

Graphically, I have a battery image that I clip according to battery percentage. I'm attempting to use `ClipDrawable` for this.

**battery_widget_layout.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/widgetLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="@dimen/widget_padding"
    android:background="@drawable/battery_clip_layer" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/batteryPercentageWidgetTextView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="@string/battery_percentage_widget_default"
        android:gravity="center" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**battery_clip_layer.xml (ie a ClipDrawable)**

```
<clip xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:clipOrientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:drawable="@drawable/battery_shape" />
```

**BatteryService.java** - a service that receives battery events and updates the widget via a RemoteViews

```
public class BatteryService extends Service {

    private static final String LOG = BatteryService.class.getName();
    private final AtomicInteger batteryPercentage = new AtomicInteger(100);

    private final BroadcastReceiver batteryUpdateReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            int level = intent.getIntExtra("level", 0);
            batteryPercentage.set(level);
            updateWidget();
        }
    };


    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        registerReceiver(batteryUpdateReceiver, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));
        Log.i(LOG, "Created...");
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        unregisterReceiver(batteryUpdateReceiver);
        Log.i(LOG, "Destroyed...");
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.i(LOG, "Started...");
        updateWidget();
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return null;
    }

    private void updateWidget() {
        final int percentage = batteryPercentage.get();
        log.i(LOG, "Updated... " + percentage);
        RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(),  R.layout.battery_widget_layout);
        remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.batteryPercentageWidgetTextView, percentage + "%");
        //ATTEMPT 1 - no cigar
        remoteViews.setInt(R.drawable.battery_clip_layer, "setLevel", 5000);
        AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(this);
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(new ComponentName(this, BatteryAppWidgetProvider.class), remoteViews);
    }

    private void updateWidgetAttempt2() {
        final int percentage = batteryPercentage.get();
        Log.i(LOG, "Updated... " + percentage);
        //ATTEMPT 2 - still no cigar
        Drawable clipLayer = getApplicationContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.battery_clip_layer);
        if (clipLayer instanceof ClipDrawable) {
            ClipDrawable clipDrawable = (ClipDrawable) clipLayer;
            int level = clipDrawable.getLevel();
            if (clipDrawable.setLevel(10000)) {
                clipDrawable.invalidateSelf();
            }
            Log.i(LOG, "Updated clip amount..." + level + " -> " + ((ClipDrawable) clipLayer).getLevel());
        }
        RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.battery_widget_layout);
        remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.batteryPercentageWidgetTextView, percentage + "%");
        AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(this);
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(new ComponentName(this, BatteryAppWidgetProvider.class), remoteViews);
    }

}
```

In `BatteryService` please have a look at the two different attempts to update the widget (`updateWidget()` and `updateWidgetAttempt2()`). Neither attempt is successful.

I feel that I'm doing something fundamentally wrong. I'm most grateful for any help/advice! :)

Comment: Your two attempts are incorrect. In the first attempt you use the `setInt()` method incorrectly as that method expects the first `int` to be the id of a `View` from the widget's layout(and not a drawable reference like you try), also there isn't a `setLevel()` method on any views, that method is present in the drawable class. Your second approach is also incorrect as all you do is load a drawable, set it's level and that's all, no relation to the widget's `LinearLayout`.

Comment: To use the `ClipDrawble` you need to be able to get a reference to it when it's already set as the background and change it's level or set its level and then set it as the background. I doubt you can do any of the above with the target view being in a widget.

Comment: @Luksprog Thanks, can you please post the above information in an answer and I'll award you the bounty.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct in that you need to set the level on a Drawable instance, but unfortunately you can't get at the Drawable because it's in a remote view.

However, ImageView does have a method called `setImageLevel`, which you can call remotely. My suggestion would be to put the Drawable in an ImageView instead of as the background of the container, and then use `setInt(R.id.image_view, "setImageLevel", level)`.

Here's what the layout should look like:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/widgetLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="@dimen/widget_padding" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/battery"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/battery_clip_layer" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/batteryPercentageWidgetTextView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="@string/battery_percentage_widget_default"
        android:gravity="center" />

</FrameLayout>
```

And the `updateWidget()` method:

```
private void updateWidget() {
    final int percentage = batteryPercentage.get();
    log.i(LOG, "Updated... " + percentage);

    RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(),  R.layout.battery_widget_layout);
    remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.batteryPercentageWidgetTextView, percentage + "%");

    remoteViews.setInt(R.id.battery, "setImageLevel", percentage * 100);

    AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(this);
    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(new ComponentName(this, BatteryAppWidgetProvider.class), remoteViews);
}
```

Comment: Yes, this was going to be my next attempt. Unfortunately, I cannot award you the bounty, as per the bounty condition "I will not award bounty to alternative solutions, eg adding an ImageView to the LinearLayout." I can however, accept your answer. I will do this once confirmed.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This works nicely, and I amable to control multiple `ImageViews` within the `FrameLayout` within the `RemoteViews`.

Answer (score 0):

The two attempts you made regarding using a `ClipDrawable` in a widget are incorrect. In the first attempt you use the `setInt()` method incorrectly as that method expects the first `int` parameter to be the `id` of a `View` from the widget's layout(and not a drawable reference like you try), also there isn't a `setLevel()` method on any `View` subclass from the Android SDK, that method is present in the `Drawable` class. Your second approach is also incorrect as all you do is load a `Drawable`, set its level and that's all, that newly created `Drawable` has no relation to the widget's `LinearLayout` root.

To make the `ClipDrawable` work you'll need to set its level to the desired value while the drawable is already set as the `LinearLayout`'s background or when you have the possibility of setting it as the background. Unfortunately I don't see how you could do this when the layout is used in a widget.

You'll need to use a workaround(Jschools provided one).